# Recording multiple meshcat visualizers

Tags: drake

I would like to record multiple meshcat visualizers with different prefix ids so I can eventually save them to an HTML file that I can interact with later. I would like the different visualizations to play on top of each other and to be able to select/unselect different visualizations.

Here is a minimal replication of the problem. I expect there to be two cartpole visualizations that are on top of each other. However, I only end up seeing one of them being recorded. The other cartpole seems stuck at the end position when I play back the recording

```
import meshcat
from pydrake.common import FindResourceOrThrow
​
from pydrake.multibody.plant import (
    AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph)
from pydrake.multibody.parsing import Parser
from pydrake.systems.analysis import Simulator
from pydrake.systems.framework import DiagramBuilder
from pydrake.systems.meshcat_visualizer import (
    ConnectMeshcatVisualizer,
)
​
v = meshcat.Visualizer()
file_name = FindResourceOrThrow(
    "drake/examples/multibody/cart_pole/cart_pole.sdf")
builder = DiagramBuilder()
cart_pole, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, 0.0)
Parser(plant=cart_pole).AddModelFromFile(file_name)
cart_pole.Finalize()
​
vis = ConnectMeshcatVisualizer(builder=builder,
                                prefix="vis",
                                scene_graph=scene_graph,
                                open_browser=False)
​
vis2 = ConnectMeshcatVisualizer(
    builder=builder,
    prefix="vis2",
    scene_graph=scene_graph,
    open_browser=False)
vis2.set_name("vis2")
​
diagram = builder.Build()
diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
​
cart_pole_context = diagram.GetMutableSubsystemContext(
    cart_pole, diagram_context)
cart_pole.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(cart_pole_context, .02)
​
simulator = Simulator(diagram, diagram_context)
simulator.set_publish_every_time_step(False)
vis.start_recording()
vis2.start_recording()
simulator.AdvanceTo(100)
vis.stop_recording()
vis2.stop_recording()
​
vis.publish_recording()
vis2.publish_recording()
​
# f = open("saved.html", "w")
# f.write(v.static_html())
# f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution.  I don't love it, but it accomplishes the stated goal.  Note the changes:

1. saving and publishing only one animation
2. naming the model in the `MultibodyPlant` with a distinct name for each sim
3. setting `delete_prefix_on_load=False` so it doesn't clear the old geometry

```
import meshcat
from pydrake.common import FindResourceOrThrow

from pydrake.multibody.plant import (AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph)
from pydrake.multibody.parsing import Parser
from pydrake.systems.analysis import Simulator
from pydrake.systems.framework import DiagramBuilder
from pydrake.systems.meshcat_visualizer import (
    ConnectMeshcatVisualizer,
)

animation = None

for i in range(3):
    file_name = FindResourceOrThrow(
        "drake/examples/multibody/cart_pole/cart_pole.sdf")
    builder = DiagramBuilder()
    cart_pole, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, 0.0)
    Parser(plant=cart_pole).AddModelFromFile(file_name, f"plant{i}")
    cart_pole.Finalize()

    vis = ConnectMeshcatVisualizer(builder=builder,
                                   scene_graph=scene_graph,
                                   delete_prefix_on_load=False,
                                   open_browser=False)
    if animation:
        vis._animation = animation

    diagram = builder.Build()
    diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()

    cart_pole_context = diagram.GetMutableSubsystemContext(
        cart_pole, diagram_context)
    cart_pole.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(cart_pole_context, .02)

    simulator = Simulator(diagram, diagram_context)
    simulator.set_publish_every_time_step(False)
    vis.start_recording()
    simulator.AdvanceTo(10)
    vis.stop_recording()
    animation = vis._animation

vis.publish_recording()
```